# WP8.1 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation' crash

Tags: crash, windows-phone-8.1, access-violation, http-live-streaming

I develop a Windows Phone 8.1 program using winRT and have an error which is not caught by VS. The only output line I get is "The program 'MyProgram.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'."
I have a HLS streaming and it occurs every time the stream ends. I thought it might be caused by calling Frame.GoBack() in non GUI thread, but I double checked this, and it is not the reason. Did anyone struggle with this kind of error and know what might be the reason or how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue in my application (Universal WP8.1 WinRT).
First, I thought it was because I wasn't using Dispatcher when calling Frame.Navigate ([see here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6d1a6be3-096e-4090-a4bd-30d1293697b3/windows-phone-81-update-1-access-violation-when-navigating-using-tapped-event?forum=WindowsPhonePreviewSDK)).

On searching further, & checking my code, I found that **calling `Frame.GoBack()` from within an event** was causing the issue. In my case, it was being called when a user toggles some option in settings page.

But, when I call `Frame.GoBack()` in the hardware back button press event handler, there is no exception. Everything worked fine.

In your case, you can just stop the streaming on stream end event, & let the user press back button to return to previous page. Or, although I haven't tried this, try using a Dispatcher:

```
await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => Frame.GoBack());
```

Hope this helps.